# how to define table model using vectors in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I was trying to link my MySQL table to my java project and I wanted to reciprocate my MySQL table on my java frame. I have written this code so far.

```
try{
    Class.forName(cn);
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, u, p);
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String q = "select eno,name,salary,dept,(salary*12) as spa from employee;";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int cc=rsmd.getColumnCount();
    Vector columns = new Vector(cc);
    Vector data = new Vector();
    Vector row;

    while(rs.next()) {
        row=new Vector(cc);

        for (int i = 1; i <= cc; i++) {
            row.add(rs.getString(i));
        }

        data.add(row);
    }

JTable table=new JTable(data,columns);
DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
jTable1.setModel(m);

} catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I have used vectors and now I'm unable to make to how to define a model for my table 'jTable1'.[MySQL table and its description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQEZD.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but this is too broad. A) don't use Vectors any more, we have List and ArrayList since Java 1.2 B) don't use raw types, we have generics for containers since Java 1.5 ( it should be something like `List<String>` for example. Then: there are many tutorials out there explaining how table models work. This community is not a replacement for you sitting down and researching this topic. First study the topic, then try to write *real* code (instead of basically dropping an empty template impl that does nothing here), and we will gladly help with specific problems.

Comment: You see, "can anybody help" is **not** a request in the scope of this community, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Im willing to help. Could you add the code attempting to add data to a jtable?

Comment: I just edited my question syntax. Please check it out. Thank You for your support.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database and read the database table rows? Tell us where you are stuck to start with.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the connection establishment is successful. I just need the way to display the data in vectors in my table.

Comment: @GhostCat,  `don't use Vectors any more` - the DefaultTableModel uses Vectors, not Lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the column names for the TableModel. Right now you just defined an empty Vector so the table thinks there are 0 columns so there is nothing to display.

You can get the column names from the ResultSetMetaData:

```
String sql = "Select * from ???";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();

//  Get column names

Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();

for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
{
    columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnLabel(i) );
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using * in SELECT.  I prefer spelling out each column name.

Comment: @duffymo, it was just an example of a quick way to show the basic logic for creating the column names Vector when you add data to a JTable. The simpler the SQL the less likely you are to make a mistake when you are testing a new concept for the first time. The OP can customize the SQL once they get the basics working. Then they know if it stops working the problem is the SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much @camickr, your code just solved my problem like a charm. It also made me learn such a fundamental thing which I will require in my everyday programs.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are learning Java programming with Swing and a database here are couple of ideas:

1. Try to do the application in stages.
2. To start with code the GUI portion only with some dummy data (not the database data; you are not connected to the database yet).
3. At this point you are able to display a window (a `JFrame`) and a `JTable` in it with some dummy data (created within the program, for example).
4. Now, code the database aspect of the application.
5. Get the data from the database table and verify you are able to read and print it to the console in your IDE.
6. Once successful, substitute the `JTable`'s dummy data with db data.
7. You should be having the application showing a window with a `JTable` and queried database data in it.

Here is the link to build `JTable` using Swing GUI at [Oracle's Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: In the tutorials I had mentioned in the answer post there is a topic Creating a Table Model - I wanted to mention it.  Also, in the same tutorials there is a section for JDBC and retrieving data from result sets. I suspect you have to populate your vector with all the rows of the db table (each vector element representing a db table row - an employee).

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a few suggestions to improve your code:

1. Don't create database connections in method scope.  Use a pool to manage them and pass the connection into the object that requires it.
2. Make your SQL a static string.
3. What is that stored procedure doing for you?  Straight, vanilla SQL should be enough to query a table.
4. You should know what your stored procedure is returning.  Why use ResultSetMetaData?
5. Per camickr's suggestion, continue with Vector b/c you're using Swing.
6. You don't close any resources in method scope.
7. Don't print the exception message to the console.  Log the entire stack trace; it'll have more information than the mere message.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your suggestions. I'm a beginner and will try to keep these points in my mind the next time I'm writing a code.

Comment: `Don't use Vector; List is a better bet` - the DefaultTableModel uses a Vector, not a List.

Comment: @camickr is an authority on Swing.  If he recommends Vector, you would do well to follow his suggestion.